# Is the file size limit for Nook epub files still 600MB?

Tags: epub, publishing, nook

Is the maximum file size for epubs sold through Barnes&Noble (via a publisher account) still 600MB?

Comment: One epub is more than 600MB? Something seems wrong with the file to me. I've never heard of an epub that large before!

Comment: Include some multimedia, namely video, in EPUB3s and that file size can easily be hit.

Answer (score 6):

I appears that [the limit is now 20MB](http://cp-barnesandnoble.kb.net/kb/?ArticleId=4342&source=Article&c=12&cid=28#tab%3ahomeTab%3acrumb:7%3aartId:4342)

> Your manuscript file must be less than 20MB in size and in one of the
>   following formats: .doc, .docx, .txt, .rtf, .htm, .html, or .epub.
>   Many manuscript files that are larger than 20 megabytes don't need to
>   be.  If your manuscript file is larger than 20MB, try reducing the
>   image size, decreasing the dots per inch (dpi), and/or increasing the
>   JPEG compression on the images in your eBook.  After applying JPEG
>   compression to the images, you should be able to get the individual
>   image files under 100 kilobytes each.

See also [The Nook Press Publishing FAQ](https://www.nookpress.com/support/faq)